# Type-check: How to check if NSData is an NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdata, multipeer-connectivity

I'm currently working with the Multipeer Connectivity Framework in XCode for an iPad App.

I want to send messages with the framework (NSStrings, Booleans & NSArrays) and Strings are working fine, but I need some sort of type-check to convert the NSData object into a String, Array, etc.

This is what my didReceiveData methode looks like:

```
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID{

    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableArray *recievedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

    if ([message isEqualToString:@"PeerIsConnected"]) {
        NSLog(@"Peer sended: Connected!");
        self.connectionIsOn = TRUE;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            [self changeConnectionButton:TRUE];
        });

        NSLog(@"Connection is on (data received) : %@", (self.connectionIsOn) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    }

    if ([message isEqualToString:@"Disconnect"]) {
        NSLog(@"Peer sended: Disconnect!");
        self.connectionIsOn = FALSE;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            [self changeConnectionButton:FALSE];
        });
    }


    if ([message isEqualToString:@"GoWasClicked"]) {

        self.muliplayergameIsOn = TRUE;
        self.myTurn = TRUE;

        self.startDate = [NSDate date];
        self.stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                                               target:self
                                                             selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                             userInfo:nil
                                                              repeats:YES];
}
```

I need some if case so I can cast the NSData object into a NSString OR NSArray OR etc.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is how the Array is sended:

```
- (void) sendArray:(NSMutableArray *) arrayToSend{

    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayToSend];

    NSError *error;
    [self.mySession sendData:data toPeers:[self.mySession connectedPeers] withMode:MCSessionSendDataUnreliable error:&error];

}
```

Comment: How is the data created (from string, boolean, array, ...) on the sending side?

Comment: I added the methode in which the array is sended...

Comment: If you're only sending an array, why would you receive anything else (absent some data garbling along  the way)?

Comment: I'm not sending only arrays, I'm sending booleans and strings as well...

Comment: BTW, the past tense of the English verb "send" is "sent" in most parts of the world.

Comment: So, are you using NSKeyedArchiver to send those as well?

Comment: I didn't use NSKeyedArchiver... But I changed all methods after Martin's advice! Now it works like charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NSKeyedArchiver` for all kinds of objects that you send
(string, array, ...). Then you can check on the receiving side with

```
id receivedObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
if ([receivedObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSArray *receivedArray = receivedObject;
    // handle array ...

} else if ([receivedObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSString *receivedString = receivedObject;
    // handle string ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But somehow the id receivedObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]; methode raises this exception: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive

Comment: @DS: Did you create the data with `NSKeyedArchiver` ?

Comment: Thank you Martin! You were right - the strings were created with NSData *data = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; obviously wrong... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Added one more condition here...

id receivedObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
if ([receivedObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSArray *receivedArray = receivedObject;
    // handle array ...
}
else if ([receivedObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSString *receivedString = receivedObject;
    // handle dictionary ...
}
else if ([receivedObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSString *receivedString = receivedObject;
    // handle string ...
}
```